# What story features an alien who lands on a warring earth and maintains he could stop it if he taught humans his language?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, languages

I have been told about a story and wondered if anyone could tell me what it is/where it comes from?

The plot is:

- An alien visitor (crash?) lands on earth
- Alien is taken prisoner by humans
- Alien comes to believe that war on earth could be stopped if humans were taught the alien's language and be better able to communicate
- Alien begs captors to let him teach his language, but to no avail
- Alien eventually killed

Comment: The idea of an alien language being fundamental to changing human behavior is in Heinlein's Stranger In A Strange Land of course, but some of the other details don't match.

Comment: Also used in Samuel Delaney's **Babel17** except here learning the language turns you into an enemy agent.

Comment: I believe this may be a story by James White from his collection The Aliens Amongst Us - unfortunately I no longer own a copy, perhaps another contributor can comment?

Comment: I have "The Aliens Among Us". Sorry  but I can't find a story that matches the description.

Comment: Vaguely reminiscent of Frank Herbert's "Try to Remember" but details don't match.